# What is the overhead in using a .NET Service Reference to call a web service?

Tags: .net, web-services, service-reference

I am consuming a web service from a third party. I am measuring the time it takes to call a web method and timing the network traffic. I am finding that the call takes considerably longer than the network traffic does.

I ran the app and used fiddler to watch the traffic and it takes 46ms to open the HTTP CONNECT Tunnel and 951ms to send the data. I would expect this total to be about 1000ms, however it is coming out at 1504ms. 500ms may not seem like much but this was done from a test server, from the live servers we are regularly seeing response times of 6 seconds, for a network call which takes 1 second.

This is the code I am using to measure the time of the web method call

```
  Dim service As New SupplementaryEnquiryV1PortTypeClient()

    Dim _stopWatch As New Stopwatch()

    _stopWatch.Start()

    response = service.Enquiry(request)

    _stopWatch.Stop()
```

The client is written in VB .NET, Framework version 4.5

The client was generated by adding a service reference in visual studio, I have also tried using svcutil.exe to generate the service reference.

I believe the web service is written in Java, but I have no access to the code. The service returns data about a single vehicle which I assume is pulled from a database.

I've tried using a service end point which was not using SSL, which made no difference.

I've tried setting the CacheSetting property on System.ServiceModel.ClientBase(Of T) to AlwaysOff and AlwaysOn and neither made any difference. I've also tried setting "Generate serialization assemblies" to On for the project.

I've used traceroute to check for any network related problems.

From Fiddler:

```
CONNECT uat-wss.xxx.co.uk:443 HTTP/1.1

ClientConnected: 15:23:20.011
ClientBeginRequest: 15:23:20.027
GotRequestHeaders: 15:23:20.027
ClientDoneRequest: 15:23:20.027
Determine Gateway: 0ms
DNS Lookup: 29ms
TCP/IP Connect: 18ms
HTTPS Handshake: 20ms
ServerConnected: 15:23:20.074
FiddlerBeginRequest: 15:23:20.074
ServerGotRequest: 15:23:20.074
ServerBeginResponse: 00:00:00.000
GotResponseHeaders: 00:00:00.000
ServerDoneResponse: 00:00:00.000
ClientBeginResponse: 15:23:20.074
ClientDoneResponse: 15:23:20.074

Overall Elapsed: 0:00:00.046

POST /TradeSoap/services/SupplementaryEnquiryV1/ HTTP/1.1

ClientConnected: 15:23:20.011
ClientBeginRequest: 15:23:20.105
GotRequestHeaders: 15:23:20.105
ClientDoneRequest: 15:23:20.464
Determine Gateway: 0ms
DNS Lookup: 0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake: 0ms
ServerConnected: 15:23:20.074
FiddlerBeginRequest: 15:23:20.464
ServerGotRequest: 15:23:20.464
ServerBeginResponse: 15:23:20.479
GotResponseHeaders: 15:23:20.994
ServerDoneResponse: 15:23:21.041
ClientBeginResponse: 15:23:21.041
ClientDoneResponse: 15:23:21.057

Overall Elapsed: 0:00:00.951
```

**Edit**

As suggested by usr I have put the code through a profiler. I have used the built in one in 2012 (see below). It looks like Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.ArrayOfObjectsSerializer1.Deserialize is taking up a lot of time. What could cause this to take several seconds?

[image: Profile Summary]

Comment: What does the web service do?  Is it perhaps processing data and/or accessing a DB which takes time on the server?  Also, what is a sample of your fiddler trace from start to response acked?  46 ms end of handshake, 951 ack of last sent packet, ??? first packet of response, ??? ack of last packet of response? (and how large is send and response data?)

Comment: I've updated the question to include the fiddler response. I'm not so interested what the web service is doing as I have no control over this. I want to know why it takes so long to create the SOAP request and receive the SOAP response.

Comment: Switch on a profiler, or pause the debugger 10 times under full load. Answering, where code is spending time, is very easy.

Comment: Try a profiler? That should tell you where the app spends its time. Otherwise all I can tell you is that the time seems excessive but I wouldn't know objectively since I do my work locally with a SSD, not on a dev server on a VM slice.

Comment: Ah, so the client send time is 1/2 second and the server think time is 1/2 second.  You're just trying to find the extra time which appears to be outside of this cycle and client related only.  Is there anything else at all going on in fiddler besides this one connect and one post?  Anything around the same time may be related.  (I don't suppose the request/response is so simple you could write a TCP test-application to run it without SSL?  That could confirm it's a client issue)

Answer (score 2):

You might be witnessing the the effects of the Nagle Algorithm, try:

```
this.webRequest.UseNagleAlgorithm.ServicePoint = false;
```

Also, the Expect100Continue 'handshake' is relevant to soap service call performance:

```
this.webRequest.Expect100Continue.ServicePoint = false;
```

Nagle will withhold sending of network packets for a short time in an effort to try and send fewer but larger data packets. Using this is perhaps a matter of etiquette when communicating over the public internet. Do your own research.

Expect100Continue will prevent the SOAP request XML being sent on the initial HTTP PUT/POST, the server will send an OK/CONTINUE and the client will then send the SOAP request XML. This additional handshaking (two full roundtrips intsead of one) will also introduce a delay.

Comment: I tried ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false but this did not seem to improve the times. ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false did seem to offer a slight improvement so I will add that to the code. 

However what I am more interested in is the time which is not being used for network access. There seems to be quite a lot of time spent which I assume is preparing to send the request or reading the response and I'm not sure why it takes so long.

Comment: Unfortunately all of the built in serialization/deserialization in .Net is appallingly slow and going by your profiler results I think that's where your problem lies. What type of bject is your 'request' parameter? I suspect that if you use XmlDocument or XDocument then you will side step the slow object serialization - worth a try. We wrote our own code here for doing SOAP calls partly because of this problem.

Comment: The request is a fairly simple object just giving Authentication information, the registration plate of the vehicle and the type of response wanted. The response is much more complex with a lot of very detailed vehicle information. I do get the feeling I am going to end up writing my own class for this soap call.

Answer (score 1):

You may be suffering because your client (the VB.Net application) is not opening more than two concurrent connections to the service.

If you have for instance 10 concurrent requests to `page.aspx`, and this page is doing one call to the service per request, you basically have a need for 10 concurrent web service calls.

But Asp.Net per default limits the number of concurrent http calls to the same target to two. So in this hypothetical case, two of the 10 page requests will actively be calling the service, the other 8 will wait for their turn. When the first two finish, two new ones will call the service and so on.

You can control this using a `web.config` setting:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="http://address.of.service/here" maxconnection="10"/>
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

See also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx), [here](http://www.danielroot.info/2009/02/improve-net-web-client-performance-by.html) or just Google for `system.net connectionmanagement maxconnection` and have a look through the results.

Note though that by significantly increasing this number, you will put much more pressure on the third party service...

Also note that changing the `maxconnection` will not improve performance of any individual service call, but it may improve performance in the production environment where the need for many concurrent calls to the service is more likely due to heavier incoming traffic to the VB.Net site.

Comment: And now that I read the question again, I notice that nowhere is there a mention of Asp.Net. The `default max 2 connections` also affect windows applications, but the `heavier traffic in prod due to incoming requests` is of course less likely the cause is such a case. I'll let the answer stand anyway in case it can be of some use...

Comment: I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx which suggests setting maxconnection to 12 * # of CPUs. So I set this value to 24 on the web servers. I will continue to monitor to see if this has improved the times.

Comment: I checked the production environment today and unfortunately this has not solved the slow responses. Having maxconnection set too low may well have been contributing to the slowness so I will leave it at 24.